# MacBook Pro app download of OBS not working as expected. Why?

Tags: macos, mac

When I try to download OBS, I need to drag the icon into application. But the OBS icon has a line through it and when i go to applications it says:

> “The application is not supported on this Mac”

But I’ve seen others do it. I have already tried multiple other ways but can’t find a way to do it. Anyone know why?

Comment: Did you check if your Mac's macOS version and CPU type (Intel vs Apple) were compatible with the version of OBS you'd downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

> “…OBS icon has a line through it…”

That means the system architecture is not supported.

Did you download Intel version on an Apple Silicon machine? Or Apple Silicon version on an Intel machine?

You need to download the version appropriate for your system architecture: Intel or Apple Silicon.

Screenshot below of the two options for download I see on my screen when I visit [OBS](https://obsproject.com)’s website:

[image]